# input type datetime-local value doesn't change if default value is set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime

**Premise**

I have a date that I format and set it as default value to an input type datetime-local. `onChange` of the input, I want to format the newly selected date/time and save it in a state. However, it just doesn't work. Below is my code.

**DateTime component**

```
import React from "react";

const DateTime = ({ value, onChange }) => {
  return <input type="datetime-local" value={value} onChange={onChange} />;
};

export default DateTime;
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import DateTime from "./DateTime";
import moment from "moment";

export default function App() {
  const [defaultDate, setDefaultDate] = useState("08/08/2020 10:00:00");
  // The above static date string comes from a context provider. Here just for the example
  const [plannedDate, setPlannedDate] = useState();

  const formatPlannedDate = (date) => {
    const d = moment(date).format("M/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
    return d;
  };

  const handleOnChange = (value) => {
    setPlannedDate(formatPlannedDate(value));
    console.log(plannedDate);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setDefaultDate(moment(defaultDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss"));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DateTime
        value={defaultDate}
        onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Link to working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-fire-mlzkm?file=/src/App.js:0-781)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It did work, but because `setPlannedDate` by `useState` is asynchronous, so it won't affect immediately. So to see changes, you should put an `useEffect` instead

```js
// ...
const handleOnChange = (value) => {
  setPlannedDate(formatPlannedDate(value));
};

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(plannedDate);
}, [plannedDate])
// ...
```

Comment: Perfect. I can now remove the extra state for default date and set it as an initial value for plannedDate itself. Thank you!